# textarea field triggers select eventlistener when any button or link is clicked in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

I have simple DOM structure with a `textarea` along with few buttons and links.
I have added [select eventlistener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select_event) to the textarea to check when user selects text.

```js
const summary = document.getElementById("summary");
summary?.addEventListener("select", (e) => {
  console.log("listening to select event...");
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <textarea id="summary" cols="30" rows="10">
    Hello how are you!
  </textarea>
  <div>
    <button type="button">Select From Textarea & Just Click</button>
    <a href="#">Select Text From Textarea & Just Click</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click on button or a tag, the select event is fired by the textarea.
Please let me know if you have an answer for this.

You can try the problem using this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/54p17eh9/6/

Answer (score 3):

To prevent false positive you may check if `document.activeElement` is actually the element you are listening the event from.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement

> The activeElement read-only property of the Document interface returns
> the Element within the DOM that currently has focus.
>
> Often activeElement will return a HTMLInputElement or
> HTMLTextAreaElement object if it has the text selection at the time.
> If so, you can get more detail by using the object's selectionStart
> and selectionEnd properties. Other times the focused element might be
> a  element (menu) or an  element.

When a button (or any other element stealing the event triggering) is clicked, it will become also the new active element giving a condition for the event handler to check which is the actual element firing the event.

Here in this demo I just check if its `id` corresponds to `summary`.

```js
const summary = document.getElementById("summary");

summary?.addEventListener("select", (e) => {
  if(document.activeElement.id === 'summary')
    console.log("listening to select event...");
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <textarea id="summary" cols="30" rows="10">
    Hello how are you!
  </textarea>
  <div>
    <button type="button">Select From Textarea & Just Click</button>
    <a href="#">Select Text From Textarea & Just Click</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this demo if you select text inside the textarea and later you click on the button, the console.log won't be invoked on the button click alone like it would if you didn't add the check.

Comment: This does solve the problem ++. But I feel like this could be done by browser but not users. Maybe there's already an issue somewhere.